# Trying to get java program to add items to an unaccepted ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I've written a java picnic game (very basic), the only thing I don't know how to do is get the program not to accept items of the same letter. I also want the program to list how many times the user entered a rejected item. Note that this allows any ordering of items, as long as no two items start with the same letter (dis-
regarding case). An acceptable sequence of inputs would be
mustard
,
ketchup
,
tofu
,
anchovies
.
However,
mustard
,
ketchup
,
tofu
, and
Kettle corn
would not work since \
Kettle corn
" begins
with the same letter as \
ketchup

### " (ignoring case).

```
import java.util.*;

public class PlayPicnic
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Picnic picnic = new Picnic();
        ArrayList<String> unaccepted = new ArrayList<>();`enter code here`

        while (picnic.numberOfItems() < 5)
        {
            System.out.print("What do you want to bring on the picnic? ");
            String item = scan.nextLine();
            if (picnic.okayToBring(item))
            {
                picnic.add(item);
            }
            else
            {

               if(!unaccepted.contains(item)) unaccepted.add(item);
           System.out.println("Sorry, you can't bring " + item);

            }
         }
        System.out.println("\nHere's what we'll have at the picnic:");
        picnic.show();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(unaccepted.toArray()));



    }
}
```

---

### corresponding class

```
import java.util.*;

public class Picnic
{
    // INSTANCE VARIABLES:
    private ArrayList<String> stuffToBring; // items to bring on the picnic

    // CONSTRUCTOR:

    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // Construct a new Picnic.
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    public Picnic()
    {
        stuffToBring = new ArrayList<String>(); // initialize list
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // Given an item s, see if it's okay to add it to the list.
    // Return true if it is, false otherwise:
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    public boolean okayToBring(String s)
    {
        // "Secret rule" -- s can't be an item already in the list:
        if (stuffToBring.contains(s)) // "contains" is in the ArrayList class
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // Given an item s, add it to the list (if it's okay to add it)
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    public void add(String s)
    {
        if (okayToBring(s)) // this test keeps people from cheating!
        {
            stuffToBring.add(s);
        }

    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // Print the items in the list
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    public void show()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < stuffToBring.size(); i++)
        {
            String s = stuffToBring.get(i);
            System.out.println(s);
        }


    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // Returns the number of items in the list:
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    public int numberOfItems()
    {
        return stuffToBring.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you reduce this down to the bare minimum code? E.g.I'm guessing the scanner based input isn't necissary for the problem

Comment: Also, wouldn't a simple way to do this be to keep a list of used first letters and then reject if the input's first letter is used?

Comment: cant afford to read all , please mention what is unaccepted ArrayList

Comment: I would certainly used approach @RichardTingle suggests. For performance list of letters could be (hash) set of letters

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom `Set` to remove duplicate, if first char is same(ignoring the case).

```
    Set<String> unaccepted =new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
          Character first=Character.toLowerCase(o1.charAt(0));
          Character second=Character.toLowerCase(o2.charAt(0));
          return first.compareTo(second);
        }           
    });
```

Now, add the value to this `Set`. It will ignore the same first `Character` data.

---

Change the while loop like below,

```
   while (unaccepted.size()<5){
        System.out.print("What do you want to bring on the picnic? ");
        String item = scan.nextLine();
        unaccepted.add(item);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is logic for checking for items in list with first char

```
public boolean checkItem(String input, List<String> items) {

        String inputFirstChar = input.substring(0, 1);
        boolean exist = false;

        for (String item : items) {

            String itemFirstChar = item.substring(0, 1);

            if(itemFirstChar.equalsIgnoreCase(inputFirstChar)) {
                exist = true;
                 break;
             }

        }

        return exist;
    }


private ArrayList<String> stuffToBring;
```

make your reference variable type with interface not the ArrayList implementation, do like this one

```
private List<String> stuffToBring;
```

Answer (score 0):

To reject words with a used first letter, you put a simple String in class "Picnic":

```
private String usedLetters = "";
```

Then in method "okayToBring" you check if the letter is already used:

```
public boolean okayToBring(String s) {
  return (usedLetters.indexOf(s.toLowerCase().charAt(0)) == -1); // letter not contained in String
}
```

and in method "add" you append the new word's first character to this String:

```
public void add(String s)
{
  if (okayToBring(s))
  {
    stuffToBring.add(s);
    usedLetters += s.toLowerCase().charAt(0);
  }
}
```

Regarding your second question, your phrasing is a bit unclear. If you want to count how many times a specific item has been unsuccessfully entered, you could use a Hashmap to store rejected Strings and their count:

```
private HashMap<String, int> unaccepted = new HashMap<String, int>();
```

Then your program's "else" clause looks like follows:

```
int newcount = (unaccepted.containsKey(item) ? unaccepted.get(item)++ : 1);
unaccepted.put(item, newcount);
System.out.println("Sorry, you can't bring " + item + "(" + unaccepted.get(item) + " unsuccessful tries)");
```

If you just want to count the total number of unsuccessful entries, use a Set and println(unaccepted.size());